# Are the conditionals equivalent: $p → q ≡ q → p$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I know that a conditional is if $p$ then $q$, but is that equivalent to saying if $q$ then $p$?

Is $p → q$ saying the same as $q → p$?

Comment: Did you try with some truth values for $p$ and $q$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft I did although I am new to propositional logic. The F's in the truth tables are in different rows for the two formulas. Not making them the same?

Comment: Right, to be the same, they must have the same values for all combinations of truth values of $p$ and $q$

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(p→q)\neq(q→p)$

$\implies (\overline{p}\lor q)\neq(\overline{q}\lor p)$

---

Consider,

$p=\text{The cricket match was played.}$

$q=\text{There was no rain.}$

Now,

$(p→q)=\text{If cricket match was played}$$\space \color{blue}{\text{then there was no rain, }}$ $\color{green}{\text{is possible and True.}}$

$(q→p)=\text{If there was no rain }$$ \color{blue}{\text{then cricket match was played,}}\color{red}{\space\text{may not be possible, so False.}}$